# sudo: What command(s) use to know its timeout, time remaining and if the timeout expired?

Tags: command-line, sudo, command

I know that `sudo commandX` asks for the user's password and if it is valid it executes `commandX` as root, until here all is ok. It is mandatory for some commands, such as `apt`, `chown`, `chmod` etc. It has sense for security reasons.

Now consider the following scenario/situation:

```
sudo commandA
... sometime
sudo commandB
```

Because `commandB` requires root permission it would run without ask for the password if the `sudo`'s timeout is not expired yet, otherwise the password must be write it again.

For `Shell Scripting` purposes, - *if is possible* - is there a command to retrieve/show the data requested for each one of the following scenarios?

- the `sudo`'s timeout - for example N minutes/seconds, it should come from according from `/etc/sudoers`
- the `sudo`'s time remaining (prior to expire). For example if the timeout is 5mins, it would return 4 or 3.5
- if the `sudo`'s timeout expired or not

So I am assuming there is a total of 3 commands or 1 command with special parameters to accomplish the goal of the scenarios

Comment: hey, small typo in first sentence: sudo doesn't ask for the *root* password, it asks for the executing user's password.

Comment: hm, you still need to write `sudo commandB` for it to be run as root, it won't do that by itself.

Comment: `sudo` timestamps need `sudo` (`root`) to access, which changes the timestamp. You can see how this works by downloading the source for `sudo`. A feature of Free Open Source Software (FOSS).

Comment: @Marcus `sudo` can be configured to ask for the target user’s password instead of the original user’s.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks and fixed - it in my case is clear since I use Ubuntu - and Ubuntu has the root without password for security reasons

Comment: you fixed my first (minor) comment, but the second one is really an issue.

Comment: @MarcusMüller fix it ... that happens after a lot of hrs of work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get case 3 by doing `sudo -n true 2>/dev/null` -- if it has nonzero status the cached authentication has expired (or been removed).

Comment: BTW - for an user that does have none configuration through in `sudoers` - therefore is impossible use `sudo` - the execution of `sudo -n <command>` **always** prints in the terminal the `sudo: a password is required` message - so `sudo -n true 2>/dev/null` *always* returns _empty_

Comment: @ManuelJordan: it _displays_ nothing, but it _returns_ nonzero status, indicating error.

Answer (score 4):

What `sudo` does is it *caches* the credentials you've entered for 5 minutes, per user, per terminal session.

For that, it simply writes an entry containing that data to /run/sudo/ts/username (or whatever `timestampdir` in sudoers points to), and checks it the next time you run `sudo`.

Any other program with access to that file (i.e. needs to be run as root) can read the same; the file format is specified in `man sudoers_timestamp`.

Sadly, it sounds like a really bad idea to make a `setsuid` program that allows users to read sudo-internal files, because for the little benefit it offers, it will have to do a lot of intense corner-case checking that, yes, the user checking entries in that file is allowed to know about the properties of that other user's sudo usage.

So, I'm afraid something like you want does not exist. Feel free to write a few lines of C++ yourself to extract the struct described in the manpage mentioned above from that file and mark the resulting executable setsuid, so that it can always be run as root, but beware that this really sounds like a dangerous thing and that there's probably better ways to do whatever you want this for.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `sudo -n true` does tell if the authentication has expired or not, but it *also* resets the timeout everytime.

Comment: BTW - for an user that does have none configuration through in `sudoers` - therefore is impossible use `sudo` - the execution of `sudo -n <command>` **always** prints in the terminal the `sudo: a password is required` message.

Comment: The time is reset with the `-v` parameter, not with `-n` - read the `man sudo` for more details

Comment: @ManuelJordan: `-v` restarts the timer _without doing anything else_, but PointLuck is nearly correct: executing any command _successfully_ (including `sudo -n true`, which is successful if the cached credential is valid) _also_ restarts the timer. That may or may not be an issue depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.